# datas are appending everytime on running stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008

Am new to Stored procedures.I wrote the stored procedure to copy table from one  dtabase to another database.On executing my stored procedures everytime My datas are added in the destination table .My row counts was increasing on every execution.

Please help to resolve the issue.Hope the problem In the loops.

My SP is:

```
--exec mall

alter procedure mall
as
begin
    declare @mallid int
    declare @mallname nvarchar(40)
    declare @mallstatus nvarchar(40)
    declare @malludsuomid nchar(2)
    declare @malludsassetcode nvarchar(6)
    declare @malludsassettype nvarchar(15)
    declare @malludsremarks nvarchar(max)
    declare @malludsdwdb int
    declare @mallsecterr int
    declare @mallassetid int
    declare @secterr int
    declare @Maxmallid int
    declare @mallentityid int

    Select @mallentityid = customtable.Bord_TableId From CRM.dbo.Custom_Tables as customtable With (NoLock) Where Upper(Bord_Caption) = Upper('Mall') And Bord_Deleted Is Null
    DECLARE cur_address CURSOR FOR

            SELECT 
            udsasset.Asset_ID,udsasset.Asset_Name,udsasset.Asset_Status,udsasset.UOM_ID, udsasset.Asset_Code,udsasset.Asset_Type,udsasset.Remarks,udsasset.DW_Key_Source_DB --,crmterr.TPro_SecTerr
        from 
            CMA_UDS.dbo.Dim_Asset as udsasset           

    OPEN  cur_address
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur_address INTO @mallid,@mallname,@mallstatus,@malludsuomid,@malludsassetcode,@malludsassettype,@malludsremarks,@malludsdwdb --,@mallsecterr
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN 
        if not exists (select crmmall.mall_MallID from CRM.dbo.Mall as crmmall where crmmall.mall_MallID = @mallid)
        begin
            exec @Maxmallid = CRM.dbo.crm_next_id @Table_Id=@mallentityid
            insert into 
                CRM.dbo.Mall
                    (mall_MallID,mall_Name,mall_Status,mall_uds_UOMID,mall_uds_asset_code,mall_uds_asset_type,
                    mall_uds_remarks,mall_uds_dw_db,mall_CreatedBy,mall_CreatedDate,mall_Secterr,mall_AMOSUploaded,mall_asset_id)
            values(@Maxmallid,@mallname,@mallstatus,@malludsuomid,@malludsassetcode,@malludsassettype,@malludsremarks,@malludsdwdb,1,GETDATE(),
                @mallsecterr,GETDATE(),@mallid)
        end
        else
        begin
            update 
                CRM.dbo.Mall 
            set 
                mall_asset_id=@mallid,mall_Name = @mallname,mall_Status=@mallstatus,mall_uds_UOMID =@malludsuomid,mall_uds_asset_code=@malludsassetcode,
                mall_uds_asset_type=@malludsassettype,mall_uds_remarks=@malludsremarks,mall_uds_dw_db=@malludsdwdb,mall_UpdatedBy=1, 
                mall_UpdatedDate=GETDATE(),mall_Secterr=@mallsecterr,mall_AMOSUploaded=GETDATE() 
            where 
                mall_MallID=@mallid
        end
        FETCH NEXT FROM cur_address INTO @mallid,@mallname,@mallstatus,@malludsuomid,@malludsassetcode,@malludsassettype,@malludsremarks,@malludsdwdb--,@mallsecterr
    end
    CLOSE cur_address 
    DEALLOCATE cur_address
End
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you inserting `crm_next_id` as the value in `mall_MallID`, but using that same id to compare with `@mallid` to see if the record is already inserted? For example, if you have id `5`, and you insert a new record with id `150`, it's not going to see that the record is already inserted when you run the SP again. Next run, it will add record with id `151`, then `152`, and so forth forever.  You shouldn't use the same field as both an auto-increment identity and a foreign key reference at the same time...

You either need to use the same `@mallid` when you insert the new records so they match, or after you generate a new id and insert into the table, update the original record `CMA_UDS.dbo.Dim_Asset` to have `Asset_ID` = `@mallid` so they are linked up properly.  Which method you use depends on the meanings of those id's and what constraints you have in your particular application.